# Left outer join in SQL with data missing in right table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have the following database schema in a Mysql database

**Users**

- id
- name

**Attendance**

- id
- user_id
- checked_on (date)

Now for a given date range I want to build a report that lists a user and another column that says whether they were present on that day or not.

I was trying to get it done using Left Outer Join using the following query

```
select * from users left outer join attendance on users.id = attendance.user_id where users.id in (11, 12);
```

How to modify the above query so that I can get the report?

Comment: Add some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```
select u.*, 
       IF(a.id IS NOT NULL, 'Present', 'Not Present') AS IsPresent 
from users u
left outer join attendance a
   on u.id = a.user_id and a.checked_on = ?
where u.id in (11, 12);
```

Comment: This works when I give a single date in the condition. But when I include a range of dates in the condition like `a.checked_on >= '2016-07-01' and a.checked_on <= '2016-07-15'` it only prints rows in which the user checked in. Is there a way to make it work for range of dates as well?

Comment: @Sudar Yes, just include the predicates `a.checked_on >= '2016-07-01' and a.checked_on <= '2016-07-15'` in the `ON` clause, **not** in `WHERE`.